# std::ifstream::open inconsistent failure

Tags: c++, c++11

I was working on a project involving `fstream` when I ran into this inconsistency. My project is failing to open a `.txt` file and in attempting to debug it I created `test.cpp` which, as far as I can tell, is functionally identical to my `main.cpp`, however they output differently when compiled and run.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


double get_pe(double price, double rent);

int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifile;
  std::string text;
  std::vector<int> price;
  std::vector<int> rent;

  // ------------------------------ Problem 1 ------------------------------ \\
  ifile.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
  if(ifile.is_open())
  {
    std::cout << "Works\n";
    ifile.close();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Fails\n";
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifile;

  ifile.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
  if(ifile.is_open())
  {
    std::cout << "Works\n";
    ifile.close();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Fails\n";
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Console Output**

```
$ g++ main.cpp | g++ test.cpp -o t.out
$ ./a.out
Fails
$ ./t.out
Works
$ ls
a.out  housingPriceAndRent.txt  main.cpp  streetAdresses.txt  test.cpp  test.txt  t.out
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

I'm really interested in what's causing this, but I haven't the slightest clue.

Comment: "I'm really interested in what's causing this" - what do you mean with "this"? What is your error message and did you already started in working with a Debugger? Also you can use ``` lang=c++ and ``` after the code to show it nice and colorful :)

Comment: Unrelated, that pipe redirect is triggering fits in the back of my head. Any particular reason you're not using && ? Regardless, if the open fails, how about a little internal probing with `perror` ?

Comment: `$ g++ main.cpp | g++ test.cpp -o t.out` Where is the command generating `a.out`?

Comment: @LarryB `g++ main.cpp` pushes to `a.out` by default. Only if you want alternate output is `-o` required.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're absolutely correct, I should be using && there... I'm not too great at bash and I'm learning as I go. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
// ------------------------------ Problem 1 ------------------------------ \\
```

Looks pretty benign right? Just a comment? But the problem is that escape character at the end. That's your way of saying "ignore this linebreak and treat the next line as if it was on this one."

So the next line:

```
ifile.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
```

is actually part of that comment!! You never run that `ifile.open()`--so *of course* `ifile.is_open()` will be false!

I would expect any IDE worth its salt to have colored this this properly so you could quickly see that that line was a comment (that's how I caught it). Notice how for me, line 18 looks green like a comment:

[image: IDE pic]